# Using LAG() on an UPDATE with CASE statements

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query on a Python Dashboard (using Plotly/Dash) that let users set some variables and update a table in BigQuery.

I'm having trouble with one query that has some CASE statements and using LAG().

I wrote the following query:

```
DECLARE cpi STRING DEFAULT "{cpi}";
UPDATE `table` SET
PAY_FT = CASE
WHEN RN = 1 AND cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY" THEN 1
WHEN RN = 1 AND cpi = "C" AND PAY_CLEAN = "PAY" THEN 1
WHEN RN = 1 THEN 0
WHEN RN > 1 AND cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY" THEN 0.2 + (LAG(PAY_FT, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY DEPTH_M))
WHEN RN > 1 AND cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY" THEN 0.2 + (LAG(PAY_FT, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY DEPTH_M))
ELSE (LAG(PAY_FT, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY DEPTH_M))
END
WHERE DEPTH_M IS NOT NULL
```

But I got the following error: **"Analytic function not allowed in UPDATE clause..."**.

I researched about it and it's caused by the LAG function, which uses de OVER clause.

I have a column named RN on my dataset, but it could use a row_number() function if it helps.

I don't know what to do to fix it.

Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big Query allows a `FROM` clause in `UPDATE` statements...

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement

So, you can write a sub-query which reads from your table and uses `LAG()` in your `CASE` expression.

Then, use the `UPDATE`'s `WHERE` clause to join that result set back on to the target table, using whatever the table's primary key is.

```
UPDATE
  table t
SET
  PAF_FT = s.PAY_FT
FROM
(
  SELECT
    <primary_key>,
    CASE
      WHEN RN = 1 AND cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY" THEN 1
      WHEN RN = 1 AND cpi = "C" AND PAY_CLEAN = "PAY" THEN 1
      WHEN RN = 1 THEN 0
      WHEN RN > 1 AND cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY" THEN 0.2 + (LAG(PAY_FT, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY DEPTH_M))
      WHEN RN > 1 AND cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY" THEN 0.2 + (LAG(PAY_FT, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY DEPTH_M))
      ELSE (LAG(PAY_FT, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY DEPTH_M))
    END
      AS PAY_FT
  FROM
    table
  WHERE
    DEPTH_M IS NOT NULL
)
  s
WHERE
  t.<primary_key> = s.<primary_key>
```